# Styles in Chromium console

Tags: css, google-chrome

i wanted to adjust my adblocker on FB and saw a very cool message in the console, i am curious how to do this.

I could not find any information how this was done on google and stackover flow ...

Steps to reproduce:
1) go to Facebook
2) open the console
3) refresh

[image]

Comment: [Styling console output](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Styling_console_output).

Comment: That is a very useful message the FB devs put in there, would be great to know how it was accomplished.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, i have to work on my google'ing skills :-)